# SQL: пересчет элементов в таблице

Tags: строки, запрос, sql

База данных гоночного симулятора

Таблица "`test`"

```
uname | pts | track
```

`uname` - имя игрока, `pts` - количество очков на трассе `track`

Запрос на вывод топа игроков:

```
SELECT uname, SUM(pts) AS S FROM test GROUP BY uname ORDER BY S DESC
```

Задача - найти количество трасс, на которых ездил игрок и вывести ее в топе, т.е. пересчитать количество строк с `track`, где встречается данный `uname`. К сожалению в `SQL` я полный ноль, даже в какую сторону гуглить не знаю. Пока читаю про вложенные запросы и уже прочитал, что они работают очень медленно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
SELECT uname, SUM(pts) AS S, COUNT(DISTINCT track) as tracks
FROM test GROUP BY uname ORDER BY S DESC
```

Если отдельная трасса для игрока может присутствовать только один раз, distinct можно убрать. В противном случае, можно проверить такой изощренный вариант на предмет поддержки:

```
SELECT uname, SUM(pts) AS S, 
(select count(*)  from (select 1 as a from test p2 where p1.uname=p2.uname
group by track) X) as tracks
FROM test p1 GROUP BY uname ORDER BY S DESC
```

Comment: Поняли Вы абсолютно верно. Но и на Ваш, и на предыдущий ответ получаю ошибку

Ошибка при разборе запроса. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 36,Token in error = DISTINCT ]

использую SQL Server Compact 4.0, оказалось что в нем функция DISTINCT не поддерживается :( 

пруф http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb896140.aspx

Comment: Это не функция. Тогда можно пожертвовать строгой семантикой и distinct убрать

Comment: @Lexanom, предложил другой вариант в ответе.

Comment: да, убрал distinct, все получилось. Большое спасибо за оперативную помощь :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT uname, SUM(pts) AS S, COUNT(DISTINCT track) FROM test GROUP BY uname ORDER BY S DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно вывести всех игроков, и сколько они каждый набрали на трассах, то это делается так:

```
SELECT uname, track, SUM(pts) AS S
FROM test
GROUP BY uname, track
ORDER BY S DESC
```

Если нужно отдельного игрока взять и сколько он набрал на трассах суммарно, то это делается так:

```
SELECT uname, track, SUM(pts) AS S
FROM test
WHERE uname = 'sampleUserName'
GROUP BY uname, track
ORDER BY S DESC
```

Если нужно вывести только одну трассу, на которой игрок набрал больше всего очков, то делайте так:

```
SELECT TOP 1 uname, track, SUM(pts) AS S
FROM test
WHERE uname = 'sampleUserName'
GROUP BY uname, track
ORDER BY S DESC
```

Вопрос задан не очень понятно, поэтому я предлагаю вам несколько вариантов, которые я смог предположить.